# Not displaying the records from the ListView with ArrayList in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I want to populate my Listview with all my saved data from the Database, however I can't retrieve all the data instead I'm getting only the first record and the count of the records itself.

MainActivity.java

```
    //Populating the ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylistData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    int[] columnIds = new int[] {R.id.tv_Lastname, R.id.tv_Firstname, R.id.tv_MI, R.id.tv_Birthdate, R.id.tv_HomeNo,
            R.id.tv_Mobile, R.id.tv_email, R.id.tv_Brgy};

    ArrayList<String> arrayPatientData = db.arrayListPatientData();
    Cursor cursor = db.getPatientData();

    for(int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++) {
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        for(int j=0; j<arrayPatientData.size(); j++) {
            Cursor cursorPatientData = db.getPatientData(j);
            //Cursor cursorCityData = db.getCityData();
            //Cursor cursorProvinceData = db.getProvinceData();

            firstname = cursorPatientData.getString(cursorPatientData.getColumnIndex(Constants.PATIENT_FNAME));
            lastname = cursorPatientData.getString(cursorPatientData.getColumnIndex(Constants.PATIENT_LNAME));
            middlename = cursorPatientData.getString(cursorPatientData.getColumnIndex(Constants.PATIENT_MNAME));
            bday = cursorPatientData.getString(cursorPatientData.getColumnIndex(Constants.PATIENT_BIRTHDAY));
            homeNo = cursorPatientData.getString(cursorPatientData.getColumnIndex(Constants.PATIENT_HOME_NO));
            mobileNo = cursorPatientData.getString(cursorPatientData.getColumnIndex(Constants.PATIENT_MOB_NO));
            email = cursorPatientData.getString(cursorPatientData.getColumnIndex(Constants.PATIENT_EMAIL));
            brgy = cursorPatientData.getString(cursorPatientData.getColumnIndex(Constants.PATIENT_BRGY));
            //city = cursorCityData.getString(cursorCityData.getColumnIndex(Constants.CITY_ID));
            //province = cursorProvinceData.getString(cursorProvinceData.getColumnIndex(Constants.PROVINCE_ID));

            map.put(FIRSTNAME, firstname);
            map.put(LASTNAME, lastname);
            map.put(MIDDLENAME, middlename);
            map.put(BDAY, bday);
            map.put(HOMENO, homeNo);
            map.put(MOBILENO, mobileNo);
            map.put(EMAIL, email); 
            map.put(BRGY, brgy);
            //map.put(CITY, city);
            //map.put(PROVINCE, province);
        }

        mylistData.add(map);
    }
    SimpleAdapter arrayAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mylistData, R.layout.attribute_patient, 
            new String[] {FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, MIDDLENAME, BDAY, HOMENO, MOBILENO, EMAIL, BRGY} , columnIds);
    lv_Patient.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

DatabaseHandler.java

```
public Cursor getPatientData(int _id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query(Constants.TABLE_PATIENT, new String[] { 
                Constants.PATIENT_ID, Constants.PATIENT_FNAME, Constants.PATIENT_LNAME,
                Constants.PATIENT_MNAME, Constants.PATIENT_BIRTHDAY, Constants.PATIENT_HOME_NO, 
                Constants.PATIENT_MOB_NO, Constants.PATIENT_EMAIL, Constants.PATIENT_BRGY,
                Constants.F_PATIENT_CITY_ID, Constants.F_PATIENT_PROVINCE_ID}, Constants.PATIENT_ID + "=?", 
                new String[] {String.valueOf(_id)}, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        db.close();
        return c;       
    }

    //Get User Data
    public Cursor getPatientData()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query(Constants.TABLE_PATIENT, new String[] { 
                Constants.PATIENT_ID, Constants.PATIENT_FNAME, Constants.PATIENT_LNAME,
                Constants.PATIENT_MNAME, Constants.PATIENT_BIRTHDAY, Constants.PATIENT_HOME_NO, 
                Constants.PATIENT_MOB_NO, Constants.PATIENT_EMAIL, Constants.PATIENT_BRGY,
                Constants.F_PATIENT_CITY_ID, Constants.F_PATIENT_PROVINCE_ID}, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        db.close();
        return c;       
    }
```

LOGCAT:

```
07-24 18:31:29.585: E/AndroidRuntime(14671): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 18:31:29.585: E/AndroidRuntime(14671): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.palsproject/com.example.palsproject.S_5th_Search_Patient}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
07-24 18:31:29.585: E/AndroidRuntime(14671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
07-24 18:31:29.585: E/AndroidRuntime(14671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
07-24 18:31:29.585: E/AndroidRuntime(14671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
07-24 18:31:29.585: E/AndroidRuntime(14671):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
07-24 18:31:29.585: E/AndroidRuntime(14671):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-24 18:31:29.585: E/AndroidRuntime(14671):    at     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-24 18:31:29.585: E/AndroidRuntime(14671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
07-24 18:31:29.585: E/AndroidRuntime(14671):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 18:31:29.585: E/AndroidRuntime(14671):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-24 18:31:29.585: E/AndroidRuntime(14671):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
07-24 18:31:29.585: E/AndroidRuntime(14671):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
07-24 18:31:29.585: E/AndroidRuntime(14671):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-24 18:31:29.585: E/AndroidRuntime(14671): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
07-24 18:31:29.585: E/AndroidRuntime(14671):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:400)
07-24 18:31:29.585: E/AndroidRuntime(14671):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
07-24 18:31:29.585: E/AndroidRuntime(14671):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
07-24 18:31:29.585: E/AndroidRuntime(14671):    at com.example.palsproject.S_5th_Search_Patient.onCreate(S_5th_Search_Patient.java:66)
07-24 18:31:29.585: E/AndroidRuntime(14671):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-24 18:31:29.585: E/AndroidRuntime(14671):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
07-24 18:31:29.585: E/AndroidRuntime(14671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
07-24 18:31:29.585: E/AndroidRuntime(14671):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Are there error messages (logcat)? What values are placed in `username`, `firstname`,... ?

Comment: @MichaelButscher, just edited my codes. I retrieve the values from each field from the database inputted by the User.

Comment: IndexOutOfBoundException --> i guess your missing a check somehwere performing something like list.length().